# java.net.SocketException:connection reset in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have a script which i run with 20 concurrent threads(Ramp up 1 sec) representing 20 companies to simulate load. Off late i have been noticing that 50 % of the companies fail.

I tried reducing the load to 15 companies but i see some failures consistently.
Kindly give you inputs on how to solve this issue.

**JMeter Log**

> 2015/06/12 00:08:27 INFO  -
>   org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$6: I/O exception
>   (org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException) caught when processing
>   request: The target server failed to respond 2015/06/12 00:08:27 INFO 
>   - org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl$6: Retrying request 2015/06/12 00:08:27 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread is done: Thread Group 1-19 2015/06/12 00:08:27 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-19
>   2015/06/12 00:08:28 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is
>   done: Thread Group 1-12 2015/06/12 00:08:28 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-12
>   2015/06/12 00:08:38 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread
>   detected by thread: Thread Group 1-8 2015/06/12 00:08:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-8
>   2015/06/12 00:08:47 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread
>   detected by thread: Thread Group 1-15 2015/06/12 00:08:47 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-15
>   2015/06/12 00:10:19 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread
>   detected by thread: Thread Group 1-14 2015/06/12 00:10:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-14
>   2015/06/12 00:10:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread
>   detected by thread: Thread Group 1-7 2015/06/12 00:10:34 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-13 2015/06/12 00:10:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-7 2015/06/12 00:10:34 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-13
>   2015/06/12 00:10:36 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread
>   detected by thread: Thread Group 1-11 2015/06/12 00:10:36 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-11
>   2015/06/12 00:12:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is
>   done: Thread Group 1-2 2015/06/12 00:12:13 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2
>   2015/06/12 00:12:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is
>   done: Thread Group 1-18 2015/06/12 00:12:14 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-18
>   2015/06/12 00:12:18 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is
>   done: Thread Group 1-17 2015/06/12 00:12:18 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-17
>   2015/06/12 00:12:19 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is
>   done: Thread Group 1-5 2015/06/12 00:12:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-5
>   2015/06/12 00:12:19 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is
>   done: Thread Group 1-1 2015/06/12 00:12:19 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1
>   2015/06/12 00:12:24 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is
>   done: Thread Group 1-9 2015/06/12 00:12:24 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-9
>   2015/06/12 00:12:24 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine:
>   Notifying test listeners of end of test 2015/06/12 00:12:24 INFO  -
>   jmeter.services.FileServer: Close:
>   /Users/dswaminathan1/Desktop/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/finale2elogin.csv
>   2015/06/12 00:12:24 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar:
>   setRunning(false,*local*) 2015/06/12 00:15:11 INFO  -
>   jmeter.gui.action.Load: Loading file:
>   /Users/dswaminathan1/Desktop/Jmeter_Final_Scripts/Final_QBOP_JSF.xml
>   2015/06/12 00:15:11 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new
>   base='/Users/dswaminathan1/Desktop/Jmeter_Final_Scripts' 2015/06/12
>   00:15:11 INFO  - jmeter.save.SaveService: Loading file:
>   /Users/dswaminathan1/Desktop/Jmeter_Final_Scripts/Final_QBOP_JSF.xml
>   2015/06/12 00:15:11 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Set new
>   base='/Users/dswaminathan1/Desktop/Jmeter_Final_Scripts' 2015/06/12
>   00:16:26 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test!
>   2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of
>   sample_variables: [] 2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  -
>   jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 2015/06/12
>   00:16:26 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting
>   ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 20 threads for group
>   Thread Group. 2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will stop on error
>   2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting
>   thread group number 1 threads 20 ramp-up 20 perThread 1000.0
>   delayedStart=false 2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1
>   2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored:
>   /Users/dswaminathan1/Desktop/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/finale2elogin.csv
>   2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread
>   group number 1 2015/06/12 00:16:26 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been
>   started 2015/06/12 00:16:27 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread started: Thread Group 1-2 2015/06/12 00:16:28 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-3
>   2015/06/12 00:16:29 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-4 2015/06/12 00:16:30 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-5
>   2015/06/12 00:16:31 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-6 2015/06/12 00:16:32 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-7
>   2015/06/12 00:16:33 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-8 2015/06/12 00:16:34 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-9
>   2015/06/12 00:16:35 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-10 2015/06/12 00:16:36 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-11
>   2015/06/12 00:16:37 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-12 2015/06/12 00:16:38 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-13
>   2015/06/12 00:16:39 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-14 2015/06/12 00:16:40 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-15
>   2015/06/12 00:16:41 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-16 2015/06/12 00:16:42 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-17
>   2015/06/12 00:16:43 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-18 2015/06/12 00:16:44 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-19
>   2015/06/12 00:16:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   started: Thread Group 1-20 2015/06/12 00:24:06 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-9 2015/06/12 00:24:06 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-9 2015/06/12 00:25:29 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-2 2015/06/12 00:25:29 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-2 2015/06/12 00:25:58 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-6
>   2015/06/12 00:25:58 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   finished: Thread Group 1-6 2015/06/12 00:26:04 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-4
>   2015/06/12 00:26:04 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   finished: Thread Group 1-4 2015/06/12 00:26:37 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-8 2015/06/12 00:26:37 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-8 2015/06/12 00:26:45 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-13 2015/06/12 00:26:45 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-13 2015/06/12 00:26:49 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-12 2015/06/12 00:26:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread Group 1-16 2015/06/12 00:26:49
>   INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group
>   1-12 2015/06/12 00:26:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   finished: Thread Group 1-16 2015/06/12 00:26:49 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-1 2015/06/12 00:26:49 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 2015/06/12 00:26:54 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-10
>   2015/06/12 00:26:54 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   finished: Thread Group 1-10 2015/06/12 00:27:08 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-18
>   2015/06/12 00:27:08 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   finished: Thread Group 1-18 2015/06/12 00:27:11 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-20
>   2015/06/12 00:27:11 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread
>   finished: Thread Group 1-20 2015/06/12 00:28:13 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-14 2015/06/12 00:28:13 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-14 2015/06/12 00:28:14 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-15 2015/06/12 00:28:14 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-15 2015/06/12 00:28:23 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-7 2015/06/12 00:28:23 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-7 2015/06/12 00:28:25 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-11 2015/06/12 00:28:25 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-11 2015/06/12 00:28:37 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-3 2015/06/12 00:28:37 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-3 2015/06/12 00:28:40 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-5 2015/06/12 00:28:40 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-5 2015/06/12 00:29:52 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-19 2015/06/12 00:29:52 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-19 2015/06/12 00:29:53 INFO  -
>   jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread detected by thread: Thread
>   Group 1-17 2015/06/12 00:29:53 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread:
>   Thread finished: Thread Group 1-17 2015/06/12 00:29:53 INFO  -
>   jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of
>   test 2015/06/12 00:29:53 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close:
>   /Users/dswaminathan1/Desktop/apache-jmeter-2.13/bin/finale2elogin.csv
>   2015/06/12 00:29:53 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar:
>   setRunning(false,*local*)

Comment: @Dmitri T - can you please take a look at this. I went over your earlier solutions and i changed the implementation too(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942583/non-http-response-message-the-target-server-failed-to-respond-is-my-server-fai). Its still not working

Comment: Can you give more details on your Test Plan, show the logs or error you get in JMeter. Are you getting the same message as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942583/non-http-response-message-the-target-server-failed-to-respond-is-my-server-fai ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK I followed (stackoverflow.com/questions/27942583/)changed the implementation to httpclient4. Its not helping.

i saw your comments where u were explaining abt the link between java and jmeter version. i am having java6 and apache-jmeter-2.13 - is that a problem ?