# Socket closed error while performing load testing on jmeter

Tags: java, sockets, jmeter

I am trying to run my load test on jmeter for REST api which is returning JSON.

I am passing the following header information in Header manager

```
 Authorization: Bearer VHFAJ0dxNQfJlzPmr7miaH4QOFeNVmez6RXVHX59uovrFAL6z5zMv9krpBAvOcNTwqHRFa8REaidlpuJSUMF8Ol38t7n-sHP2WQn0KmrEnFrtdo6XDRdhspVP1D72oIlu9sP_-rdv1MdsnakVewqrzZ9PeDiWhVKqRBTjWVlnZFpLS-CZ86DFanQ9cw7VZ67a1yOWC7_os7vZYeIhaQ8dM_8n_ocYzFDcCHELSGqnz3NHc9DRrQQfjM6xB17aRjUKQ4ZNV52Ss_1BKG8-5H7bMpi1QiAdDS17K55WrNAZMzgHeaP6UwtQwJyo_gxiaW5PlNJZNQQn4rZvNkIRd_V9Q
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded 
Accept: application/json
```

Few days ego I tried the same test on local internal server and it was working fine. Now I am running this on UAT env which is setup on AWS.

This is working fine with chrome Postman extension.

Also I have followed the below link but no success and getting the socket closed exception

[Non HTTP response message: The target server failed to respond: Is my server failing to handle load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942583/non-http-response-message-the-target-server-failed-to-respond-is-my-server-fai)

> java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>       at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:127)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
>       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
>       at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Please let me know if more information is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your UAT deployment is behind Elastic [Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/de/elasticloadbalancing/) or [Elastic IP](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) it may be the situation when JMeter resolves IP address of only one server and it becomes overloaded while others are idle.

Try adding [DNS Cache Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#DNS_Cache_Manager) to your Test Plan to see if it helps. Check out [The DNS Cache Manager: The Right Way To Test Load Balanced Apps](https://blazemeter.com/blog/dns-cache-manager-right-way-test-load-balanced-apps) guide for more information on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

You should read this:

- https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterSocketClosed

Note Socket closed can be an issue with your server.