# Always getting error “Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException”

Tags: java, multithreading, jmeter, stress-testing

I tried stress testing with JMeter software to test a web site as it crashed after a sms campaign. Currently site has been moved to a physical server.

I tested multiple times by adding threads, it worked and gave few errors (for above 1000 threads), and worked for 400 threads with no error. So I tried distributed testing with 4 PCs including my one.

After I tried again with only my PC to send requests to the site by adding 400 threads(ramp up = 1 , loop = 1). But each and every requests gives error. Then I tried using 1 thread. Same error was given.

[image]

I checked my network connection, and there is no problem. Then I browsed the web site "http://www.myjobs.lk/", and it works fine.

These are the values I have given in testing.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Under this condition, I cannot perform the testing because it always gives errors. How can I overcome this problem?

Comment: i don't know why error is occurung in your case but in my case this error occurs everytime when my internet connection does not work. Make sure your internet should be working fine.

Comment: Internet connection is fine and Can access the web site, no problem of it

Comment: @TharinduKandegedara Can you check and show the values you are using for `Server Name or IP` and `Path` fields in  `HttpRequest` or `HttpRequestDefaults` screen

Comment: You could try to switch the sampler implementation to Java or HTTPClient4 or look at this [Click me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27942583/non-http-response-message-the-target-server-failed-to-respond-is-my-server-fai)

Comment: You don't need to post four screenshots to describe an `UnknownHostExceptuon`. Let me explain. It means that the hostname you tried to connect to is unknown. To the DNS. It's wrong. Fix it, or fix your DNS.

Comment: So @EJP Can you give it as a answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using incorrect JMeter configuration, change it as follows:

1. Remove `http://` from "Server Name or IP" input
2. Put `http` to "Protocol input

   [image: HTTP Request Defaults]

   It is also possible to have the full URL in "Path" field like

   [image: Path in HTTP Request Defaults]

   But using "http://" in "Server Name or IP" won't work.

Also once you defined hostname, port, path, etc. in HTTP Request Defaults it will be automatically applied to all [HTTP Request Samplers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request). You will be able to override an option for particular this or that sampler but if you don't - default value will be used. See [Why It's SO Important To Use JMeter's HTTP Request Defaults](https://blazemeter.com/blog/http-request-defaults) for more detailed explanation and some use cases.

Comment: I think this is the solution for the IllegalArgumentException caused by putting in a "http://" in the server name or IP from my answer, not the UnknownHostException which was the original question? Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

For me it was helpful to setup proxy server: 
[image: Http Request Defaults-> Advanced]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `JMeter` tries to connect to `myjobs.lk`, and you browse to `www.myjobs.lk`. Try changing so that `JMeter` also connects to `www.myjobs.lk`

Comment: I tried it @gustf , but after that it give another error. I was unable find the problem. I mentioend it in my question.

Comment: I think you now changed it to include "http://", which is not the server name or IP (look at the answer from @Dmitri). I updated my answer with no "http://" to minimize confusion.